# Laravel app: importing live database locally causes failure in when trying to login user accounts

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, laravel-passport, laravel-10

I am working on a `Laravel` app with `Passport` installed and configured. Recently, I found a bug that only happens on the `live` site so I decided to import the live database locally on my dev machine to debug the problem. However, for some reason, once imported, I can no longer log into any of the accounts nor change the passwords of the accounts through any means (I mean it might work but it does not help with login).

As I said, I tried resetting the passwords through the password reset form. I tried creating a new route that changes the password for a specific account I am trying to login with.

We also have a staging site, importing db from staging works just fine.

`oauth-public.key` and `oauth-private.key` used in `Passport` are the same across local, staging and production. Env's `APP_KEY` is also the same.

This is all running in `Docker`. The `passport` endpoint returns `401` when trying to login the user.

Everything in `.env` seems fine.

Any ideas? I am running out of those myself.